# Solve squared (non-linear) system with two equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I want to solve this two non-linear equations for t1 and t2 and do an implementation in C++ afterwards. (Only with the solution functions for t1,t2 only).

Each of the equations should result in 2 solutions, therefore at all 4 solution.

```
I:  x1*t1^2 + y1*t1 - x3*t2^2 - y3*t2 + z1 == 0
II: x2*t1^2 + y2*t1 - x4*t2^2 - y4*t2 + z2 == 0

x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4,z1,z2 are known
t1,t2 are only unknown and should be calculated
```

In Matlab is is possible to solve it easily with

```
solve(I,II,[t1 t2])
```

, but I am not able to to is by hand to get the 4 equations to calculate t1/t2.

How can I do this? Or which kind of topic is this problem?

Update:

My question is based on the following solution for the intersection of two rotated parabola, which results in

```
0 = xa'(t1) - xb'(t2)
0 = ya'(t1) - yb'(t2)
```

In [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129815/code-or-formula-for-intersection-of-two-parabolas-in-any-rotation/129889#comment65248483_129889) he describes:

> Each of these equation is just a order 2 polynomial. These are easy to solve.

Comment: So, you know the values of all x, y, z?

Comment: Maybe you can use 'fsolve' instead ?

Comment: I know all values, t1 t2 are the only variables. Updated question.

Comment: @Curious: fSolve is another function of matlab, (solves it numerically, if I remember correct). But I would like to be able to implement it in C++ afterwards. Therefore I would like find a generic solution. But I will have a look at it.

Comment: OpenCV (c++ library) provides a function used to "perform non-linear non-constrained minimization of a function". Is this the same problem as I have?
http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-alpha/modules/core/doc/optim.html#downhillsolver